# Cannot read property push of null

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs-scope

while pushing an  element for the first time to a child array which is null,I'm getting this error
"Cannot read property push of null"
But the element gets pushed,and the second time I do everything goes fine.It gets added to the array

```
this.group.departmentsList.push({
    name: group.newCategoryName,
    sortOrder: group.departmentsList.length,
    type: "category"
});
```

group contains the data and departmentList is the child array which is declared like this:

```
 $scope.parentDepartment = [
    {
        departmentsList: [{}]
    }
];
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Well don't push to nonexistent array maybe? You can explicitly check if it's not null and create one if needed:

```
this.group.departmentsList = this.group.departmentsList || [];
this.group.departmentsList.push({
    name: group.newCategoryName,
    sortOrder: group.departmentsList.length,
    type: "category"
});
```

Comment: i like this technoque. helped me a lot. also its shorthand, easy to use