# i got error : Cannot read property 'push' of null

Tags: javascript

I tried like [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26273043/cannot-read-property-push-of-null), but it did not work anyway.

This is a new thing for me, and just started learning javascript.

```
var getTbl = localStorage.getItem("tableList");
var resultTable = [];
if (getTbl !== undefined && getTbl !== '') {
  resultTable = JSON.parse(getTbl);
}
let newtableHTML = addTable;
resultTable.push({
  table: newtableHTML
});
// save the new resultFolder array
localStorage.setItem("tableList", JSON.stringify(resultTable));
```

i try something like this, but no luck :

```
var resultTable = resultTable || [];
```

*Sorry if I'm wrong in trying that way.*

Comment: getTbl is propably setting resultTable as null
``if (getTbl !== undefined && getTbl !== '') {
  resultTable = JSON.parse(getTbl);
}`` check this portion of your code

Comment: Wild guess, but I think the value of 'tableList' stored in the local storage was once accidentally set to `null` and that value is now returned in all instances. Try clearing your local storage from the developer tools and try run your code again.

Comment: `localStorage.getItem` returns null if the key does not exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line

```
resultTable = JSON.parse(getTbl);
```

*replaces* the contents of the `resultTable` variable with whatever `JSON.parse` returns. Apparently `JSON.parse` is not returning an array (or other kind of object with a `push` method, but arrays are the only built-in ones that do).

My guess is that it's returning `null`, because `getItem` returns `null` if the key doesn't exist in local storage, but you're not checking for that. So you're passing `null` into `JSON.parse`, it gets coerced to string (`"null"`), and then parsed as JSON, yielding...`null`.

Since you're storing an array (and arrays are never falsy), I'd probably do this:

```
var getTbl = localStorage.getItem("tableList");
var resultTable = getTbl ? JSON.parse(getTbl) : []; // <====
let newtableHTML = addTable;
resultTable.push({
  table: newtableHTML
});
// save the new resultFolder array
localStorage.setItem("tableList", JSON.stringify(resultTable));
```

That tests if what `getItem` gave us was falsy and, if it is, uses `[]` instead.

But there are a dozen variations on this theme. For instance:

```
var resultTable = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tableList") || "[]"); // <===
let newtableHTML = addTable;
resultTable.push({
  table: newtableHTML
});
// save the new resultFolder array
localStorage.setItem("tableList", JSON.stringify(resultTable));
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the way 'resultTable' is initialised to :

```
resultTable = new Array();
```

So that  data can be pushed properly to resultTable.